# Borel-Weil-Bott theorem for wonderful compactification in characteristic p

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, characteristic-p, compactifications

Are there any known results for a Borel-Weil-Bott theorem for the wonderful compactifications over characteristic $p$ (i.e., theorems that classify the cohomologies of all line bundles on a wonderful compactification)?

In characteristic $0$, Syu Kato proves this result in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869302005690?via%3Dihub), working over $\mathbb{C}$.

In characteristic $p$, it is known that higher cohomologies vanish for line bundles corresponding to dominant weights, for example as in Theorem 3.2 in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01457285).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The "usual" Borel-Weil-Bott theorem on varieties $G/B$ fails in positive characteristic, and $G/B\times G/B$ sits inside the wonderful compactification $\widehat{G}$ as the common intersection of all boundary divisors.  So my intuition suggests that Borel-Weil-Bott also fails for $\widehat{G}$ in positive characteristic.